# Jenkins 2.4 compatibility with sonarqube and nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, nexus

Is jenkins 2.4 compatible with sonar 6.2 , sonar 4.5.7 and nexus 2.11, nexus 2.13 ?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning compatibility between SonarQube and Jenkins, you can have a look at: https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html

But for sure there is no more official support of SonarQube 4.5.7 since current LTS is 5.6.x